# What do the 2 venvs mean in the console

Tags: python, python-venv

Why are there 2 venvs in parenthesis?

[image: doublevenv]

I couldn't find anything on google about what having 2 venvs means.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.  Paste the text in the question.  Images are not readable by screen readers and can't be indexed or searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deactivating the current venv with
`deactivate`
You might have started a virtual environment in a virtual environment, therefore the venv shows twice in your console